# Bash parameter expansion from both sides

Tags: bash, variables, parameters

I'm getting dollar values from a file into the variable in the form
p=$1234.56, and would like remove $ and decimal places to get integer value in my conditional like

```
if [[ ${p%%.*} < 1000]]; then p=${p}0; fi
```

But this doesn't remove the $ sign, and I don't want to do it in 2 steps and modify actual variable, as I need $ for later use.
How to get integer value regardless of number of digits ie ($2.2, $123456.1234...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option will be to use `cut` command to extract the substring
before the dot (if any). Then you can say something like:

```
p='$1234.56'
[[ $(cut -d. -f1 <<< "${p#\$}") < 1000 ]] && p=${p}0
echo "$p"
```

BTW the expression `[[ str1 < str2 ]]` performs *lexicographical comparison,*
meaning `[[ 20 < 1000 ]]` returns `false` because `20` sorts *after*
`1000` in dictionary order.

If what you want to do is arithmetic comparison, you'll need to say
`[[ val1 -le val2 ]]` or `(( val1 < val2 ))` such as:

```
p='$1234.56'
[[ $(cut -d. -f1 <<< "${p#\$}") -le 1000 ]] && p=${p}0
echo "$p"
```

Comment: Good catch with the lexicographical comparison. You still want to avoid external processes when you can.

Comment: Thanks @tshiono , that is working but if I set variable without quotes it will remove one more digit.... probably because it seems like a variable

Comment: Thanks also for clarifying comparisons, I always mess them up

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid performing multiple [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) if you need to remove multiple patterns, in the general case.

In simple cases like this, you can avoid a temporary variable just by assigning back to the same variable.

```
p=${p#\$}
p=${p%.??}
```

In your specific scenario, of course, you can just replace any nonnumeric characters globally, and accept that the number will be multiplied by 100. You will obviously then need to multiply the number you compare against correspondingly.

```
if [[ ${p//[!0-9]/} < 100000 ]]
```

Of course, for this to work, you need to be sure  that your variable's value conforms to your expectations. If the value could have different numbers of decimal places depending on what a user passes in or where you read the input from, you need to perform additional normalizations, or just use a different approach entirely (frequently you'd pass your input to Awk or `bc` which support floating point math, unlike the shell).

However, the string substitution parameter expansion `${variable//pattern/replacement}` is a Bash extension, and not portable to Bourne/POSIX `sh`.

Comment: can you do nested parameter expansion?

Comment: "...and modify actual variable, as I need $ for later use."

Comment: The way I understand the question, it says "and don't want to ... modify the variable" as they need the original value later.

Comment: I don't want to modify my variable, as it running through many loops and only one such case is applicable

Comment: Of course, there's nothing to force you to assign back to the original variable. If you want to avoid that, assign to a temporary variable after all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without modifying the var. But you can use a subshell process with something like `sed`

```
if [[ $(sed 's/\$\([0-9]*\)\..*/\1/' <<< $p) < 1000 ]]; then p=${p}0; fi
```

Comment: if p=$987.67 then output echo  `$(sed 's/\$\([0-9]*\)\..*/\1/' <<< $p) ` is 87.65

Comment: Not sure what is this \1 in substitution?

Comment: @DenisZ you have to set `p` like this `p='$987.67'`

Comment: `\1` means 1-st group, group is defined within \(...\). In this case it's any number(*) of digits([0-9]) between `$` and `.` So it changes whole string to just 1-st group.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan I've noticed my mistake without quotes

Comment: but in my script I call variable with commands like: 'p=`grep \>$YDY\< -A 11 $CRY.html |sed -n 12p| sed 's/,//g'`'  so single quotes wouldn't work, but I've tested it again and it's working fine now even if I don't put variable in quotes